# Specify the adminsitrative level in QuickOSM

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, administrative-boundaries, quickosm

I am using QuickOSM to download the boundaries of cities into QGIS before saving each city data as a GeoJSON. QuickOSM enables the Key (in my case, 'boundary') and Value ('administrative) to be specified, but I don't know how to specify the administrative level (admin_level=x). However, I need to do this to get the boundaries for the actual city. At present, I get boundaries for the wrong administrative level. For instance, running the query for 'Amsterdam' outputs the boundaries for the Netherlands as a whole. What can I include in the Overpass Query to specify the administrative level?
[image: Shown here]
[image: this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having just:

```
<has-kv k="boundary" v="administrative"/>
```

You should add a line:

```
<has-kv k="boundary" v="administrative"/>
<has-kv k="admin_level" v="8"/>
```

I also removed sections for `node` and `way`:

```
<osm-script output="xml" timeout="25">
    <id-query {{geocodeArea:amsterdam}} into="area_0"/>
    <union>
        <query type="relation">
            <has-kv k="boundary" v="administrative"/>
            <has-kv k="admin_level" v="8"/>
            <area-query from="area_0"/>
        </query>
    </union>
    <union>
        <item/>
        <recurse type="down"/>
    </union>
    <print mode="body"/>
</osm-script>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, just getting strated with Overpass syntax.